# Could not find rack-cache-1.0.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bundler, rack-cache

I have created a very basic Rails 3.1 app, deployed to a box that runs Ruby 1.8.7 (P334) (I can't easily go to 1.9.2. there unfortunately).

After deploying and running 'bundle install' I tried to run a console:

```
bundle exec rails console
```

And I get:

> Could not find rack-cache-1.0.3 in any of the sources

and the console does not come up.

It seems that this particular version of rack-cache is listed as a dependency by ActionPack 3.1.0.

Can someone explain to me what I need to do to resolve this, i.e. get bundler to attach this version of rack-cache to the project?

Also I read that bundler stores the project-specific GEMs 'somewhere else', i.e. no longer in the global Ruby GEM path. Is there a default location for this project specific place ?

Oh and I also keep getting heaps of 'invalid gemspec' warnings with Rails 3.1, i.e.:

> Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00:00:00.000000000Z"

Comment: Why does this happen in the first place? I'm getting it regularly, particularly on os x

Comment: You should mark the answer that worked for you as accepted/correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into this issue when upgrading my Rails 3.0 app to 3.1.

Edit the `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec` file and set `s.date = %q{2011-08-27}`. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! After I corrected all the dates in offending gemspec's, it's working great now!

Comment: If you continue to get the error you either didn't save the file(s) or edited the wrong file(s).